# Quickbooks SDK, XP and version 24.0.4006.0 woes

Tags: windows-xp, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We're a 3rd party software suite that interfaces with Quickbooks via the QB SDK.  A dozen+ of our customers are using Windows XP (yes), and some of them very recently installed QB's update 24.0.4006.0.   Which has broken the programmatic interface before our app and QB.   Specifically, our XP customers are reporting back "procedure entry point EnumProcessModulesEx could not be located in the dynamic link library PSAPI.dll".  QB itself is working, for now, which is putting focus on our software at this point.

Anyone else seeing this conflict, between 24.0.4006.0 and XP ?  Beyond trying to back out the 24.0.4006.0, or getting these custs off XP, could anyone suggest a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

all:

info this AM on this problem, workaround : "You can use an R5 or earlier version of QBXMLRP2.dll to fix the problem until  fix is available."

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some additional information.

Intuit has officially ended support for Windows XP with their QuickBooks product line. Pop over to Intuit and check out the requirements documents, specifically the Operating System support for details.

Right now, the only way to restore functionality would be to get the user to uninstall QuickBooks completely from their PC, then have them reinstall QuickBooks. Do not take them past R5 (release 5, IE: update/service pack 5) and the DLL will still be functional.

Full details on this re-installation process are available from Intuit at http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/SLN86786